# .htaccess Redirect Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect `http://www.example.co.uk` and `http://example.co.uk` to 
`https://example.co.uk`.

In the `.htaccess` file I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects the one starting with www. but how I redirect the other as well without the "too many redirects" error occuring?

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use two separate rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://mysite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://mysite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you I gave that a try and still the redirect error occurred. This is really quite confusing!

Comment: Make sure you are not looking at a cached result please.

Comment: I have made sure, still get the same result.

Comment: The answer was: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} !=1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]