# .htaccess redirecting both www and non-www to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using `.htaccess`. I am trying to redirect `http://www.example.co.uk` AND `http://example.co.uk` to the secure https. I have searched on this site and tried all the suggestions, but none work. I have approached my hosting company and they have tried with no joy.

One example I used is -

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Another example code I use is -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://zapstudio.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

The error comes up as follows on Firefox:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

There is no other coding in my .htaccess file than the code inserted. Please, can anyone shed any light on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess Redirect Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803286/htaccess-redirect-error)

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through all that need help on this issue, but it has not solved my problem

Comment: How is the SSL managed? See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743283/htaccess-rewrite-too-many-redirects

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I have no idea how the SSL is managed. I am not a coding man, and I don't understand all the technicalities. All I have done is used just about all the snippets of coding people have kindly posted, and non seem to work.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to your question, you will probably need to include your entire `.htaccess` file since the order matters and you can get conflicts with other directives.

Comment: I have so many code snippets I have lost count, but I this this is the last one I used -

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

Comment: Clear your browser cache. If you have nothing in your htaccess then it's a caching issue. Don't test with 301, use 302 until you know your rules work how you want them.

Comment: What about the contents of your `.htaccess` file? Or is that your entire file?

Comment: My hosting company has fixed it. All is working great now. They said it was something to do with cache. I did empty my browser cache but it was still doing it. My host said cache is on many levels, can't understand what they were on about. Anyway, thanks for your help w3dk and Panama Jack.

Comment: @Zaptabby Thanks for the feedback. You can add that as an answer (and later accept it) - this removes the question from the unanswered question queue. However, although caches are indeed on "many levels", it's unusual that the problem would be a server-side caching issue that your host would be able to resolve?

Comment: That's what they said, I have no idea what they did, but its working :-)

Comment: Are you suggesting it was something else they did?